# Calathea Iancifolia- Rattlesnake plant- has stopped moving its leaves up and down

Tags: leaves

My rattlesnake plant has stopped “praying” at night and the leaves are become dried and faded. I moved in to a shadier spot but haven’t seen improvement. I have also watered it more.  Can anyone help? [image]